# Swiftui widget ios 17

Tags: swiftui, bluetooth, widget

can i ask about widget lifecycle of widget, i have simple widget with button, and search ble devices.

when i debug, works fine. devices is discovered

but when runing without debugger, sometime working, sometime not, i have allowed

- external accessory communication
- uses ble communication
- acts as ble
- background fetch
- background processing

but without any success,

my code data services scan ble devices

```
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
class EasyOpenAppIntent: AppIntent {

    static let title: LocalizedStringResource = "Create a Transfer"
    static let description: LocalizedStringResource = "Starts a new File Transfer"
    
    let dataService: WidgetDataAdapter = WidgetDataAdapter()
    
    required init () {}
    
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
    
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            self.dataService.scan()
        }
        
        return .result()
    }
    
    
}

public struct TestIntents: AppIntentsPackage {}
```

do you have any idea ?

Comment: DispatchQueue and async await are not compatible the new concurrency is a replacement you may be having threading issues

Comment: ok, i have before without dispatch, no discovered devices